# Не могу отправить окно с оплатой YooKassa в Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Вечер добрый, сегодня добавляя оплату в своего Telegram бота столкнулся с такой проблемой, что запрос оплаты не отправляется.

Запрос:

```
    elif call.data == 'buyplus':
        bot.send_invoice(

            chat_id=call.from_user.id,
            title="*my title*",
            description="*my desc*",
            invoice_payload="*my payload*",
            provider_token="*my YooToken*",
            currency="RUB",
            start_parameter="bot",
            prices=[{
            "label":"Руб",
            "amount":15000
            }]

        )
```

Ошибка:

```
2022-01-17 21:57:11,178 (__init__.py:694 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the 
Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: there must be at 
least one price"
```

Comment: А текст ошибки перевести?

Comment: В том то и дело, что всё сделано по документации. Несколько раз перепроверял. Не могу понять, почему именно выпадает данная ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя долгое время нашёл тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700737/how-to-send-send-invoice-method-using-telebot решение своей проблемы. Она заключалась в том, что я отправлял запрос методами присущими библиотеке aiogram, когда мой бот написан на библиотеке telebot.